# How to ensure (and wait), that all promises are in settled state in javascript?

Tags: javascript, promise

My function (not `async`) calls getUserMedia several times (in a loop `for`). 
Every call creates a promise, then resolve- or reject-handler will be called.

After the loop exits I need to ensure, that all promises are settled, collect results and perform a `return` for the `function`.

So I need to ensure, that all promises are settled in the point (C) – see following code, process results of it’s handlers, and exit the function.
Is my code correct ?

I am confused, that my program will wait in a loop.

I could process the result in the point (A), but if I do it and perform `return`, then it will exit resolve_handler but not the function.

On the other hand, if I will process results and perform `return` in the point (B), then I will not ensure, that all promises settled ?

So, how can I ensure it ?

```
       let promisesToWait = [];

        for (let constraintIndex = 0; constraintIndex < constraintsArray.length; constraintIndex++) {
            let curConstraints = constraintsArray[constraintIndex];

            let curPromise = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(curConstraints);
            promisesToWait.push(curPromise);

            // process a promise returned by getUserMedia
            curPromise.then(
            function Resolve_GetUserMedia(stream) {
                // --- there is the resolve_handler ---
            } // function Resolve_GetUserMedia(stream)
            ,

            function Reject_GetUserMedia() {
                // --- there is the reject_handler ---
            } // function Reject_GetUserMedia() {

            );
        } // for (let constraintIndex = 0,

        let allPromises = Promise.allSettled(promisesToWait);

        // --------- wait when all promises will be settled ---------
        let finishWaiting = false;
        allPromises.then(   () => {/*resolve:*/ finishWaiting = true;
        // ================= the point (A)
                                  },
                            () => {/*resolve:*/ finishWaiting = true;}                
        ); // then
        // ====================== the point (B)
        let startTime = Date.now();
        let loopsCounter = 0;
        while (!finishWaiting) {
            loopsCounter++;
        }
        let finishTime = Date.now();
        let waitingDuration = finishTime - startTime;
        // +++ output waiting statistics +++
        let msg = "Wating statistics: time (ms) = " + waitingDuration + ".  Waiting loops = " + loopsCounter;
        DisplayLog2Message(msg);
        console.log(msg);
        // ======================== the point (C)
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `Is my code correct?` No. You __can not__ synchronously wait for asynchronous things. Its  not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach of using a loop to wait for promises to settle `(while (!finishWaiting))` is not recommended. It leads to blocking the event loop and might result in poor performance or even freezing the application.

Instead, you should leverage the asynchronous nature of promises and use the `await` keyword or handle the settled promises inside the `then` block. Here's an updated version of your code using `async/await`:

```js
async function yourFunction() {
    let promisesToWait = [];

    for (let constraintIndex = 0; constraintIndex < constraintsArray.length; constraintIndex++) {
        let curConstraints = constraintsArray[constraintIndex];

        let curPromise = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(curConstraints);
        promisesToWait.push(curPromise);

        // Process a promise returned by getUserMedia
        curPromise.then(
            function Resolve_GetUserMedia(stream) {
                // --- there is the resolve_handler ---
            },
            function Reject_GetUserMedia() {
                // --- there is the reject_handler ---
            }
        );
    }

    // Wait for all promises to settle
    await Promise.allSettled(promisesToWait);

    // Process results or perform other actions
    // This point is reached only when all promises are settled
    // ================= the point (C)
    // ...

    // You can return something here if needed
}

// Call your function
yourFunction().then(() => {
    // Any code you want to execute after all promises are settled
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error:", error);
});
```

By using `await Promise.allSettled(promisesToWait)`, you ensure that the function doesn't proceed beyond that point until all promises are settled. The `then` block following the `await` is where you can process the results or perform actions once all promises are settled. Additionally, the use of `async/await` makes the code more readable and avoids blocking the event loop.

Comment: thank you very much. If instead of your proposal in yourFunction() I call `return allPromises`, yourFunction will not be `async`. And it's caller will call resultOfYpurfunc.then(...) - will the effect be equal to your proposal ?

Comment: AI generated content is [currently banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/20153035) on Stack Overflow. Please read the [AI Policy](/help/ai-policy) for more information.

Comment: My pleasure to contribute to this problem.
By the way, if this solution is working for you then I'll be happy :)

Comment: It is not recommended to mix `.then()` and `await`.  Pick one model or the other, not both.

Comment: @jfriend00, thanks for the review. I agree with you. Stying with the same model is good for the code writer and reviewer.

But I think if the function `"export const yourFunction"` is exported then it's a fully new promise resolver. Users can call in different files or inside of a new function to fulfill the promise.

Maybe using `func().then().catch()` is not an issue, just a good practice.